# Why pass cancellation token to TaskFactory.StartNew?

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

Besides the most common form of calling TaskFactory.StartNew with only the "action" parameter 
(1) https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321439(v=vs.110).aspx

we alse have one method that accepts an extra parameter as the "Cancelation Token"
(2) https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd988458.aspx

My question is, why should we use the call (2) instead of call (1)?

I mean, the example in MSDN for page (2) would also work if I don't pass the Cancellation Token as parameter (because the variable token is accessible from the delegate function. Something like:

```
var tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
      var token = tokenSource.Token;
      var files = new List<Tuple<string, string, long, DateTime>>();

      var t = Task.Factory.StartNew( () => { string dir = "C:\\Windows\\System32\\";
                                object obj = new Object();
                                if (Directory.Exists(dir)) {
                                   Parallel.ForEach(Directory.GetFiles(dir),
                                   f => {
                                           if (token.IsCancellationRequested)
                                              token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                                           var fi = new FileInfo(f);
                                           lock(obj) {
                                              files.Add(Tuple.Create(fi.Name, fi.DirectoryName, fi.Length, fi.LastWriteTimeUtc));          
                                           }
                                      });
                                 }
                              }
                        ); //note that I removed the ", token" from here
      tokenSource.Cancel();
```

So is there anything happening underneath when I pass cancellation token to Task.Factory.StartNew?

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Two things will happen.

1. If the token has been canceled before StartNew is called it will never start the thread and the task will be in the `Canceled` state.
2. If a [`OperationCanceledException`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.operationcanceledexception(v=vs.110).aspx) is raised from inside the task and that exception was passed in the same token as `StartNew` it will cause the returned Task to enter the `Cancelled` state. If the token associated with the exception is a different token or you did not pass a token in the task will enter the `Faulted` state.

**P.S.** You should never call `Task.Factory.StartNew` without passing in a [`TaskScheduler`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler(v=vs.110).aspx) because if you don't it can easily [cause you to run code on the UI thread that you expected to run on a background thread](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html). Use `Task.Run(` instead unless you absoultely need to use `StartNew`, `Task.Run` has the same `CancellationToken` behavior as `StartNew`.

Comment: Thank you for spreading the word about not using `Task.Factory`